# package manager did not install properly

Tags: package-management

After downloading ubuntu 14.04.01 I had problems with getting the package manager to work properly. when I tried to update using and I got this error message: Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f :I tried this as well in terminal and it did not work I get an error code 1

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go to Ubuntu Software Center and ask for a Repair and check the status.

Comment: Can you expand on how to do that?